# How to use Dropbox for storing images instead of Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, dropbox, spree

Hello there I am planning to host my Spree site on Heroku, but as Heroku's filesystem is read only, the Spree documentation site has suggested to use Amazon's S3. The problem in using S3 is that, I don't have credit card. I am a student from Nepal. 
So, I want to know if there is any way to use Dropbox to store images for my Heroku hosted Spree site?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your assets such as images to your Heroku apps GIT repository and push it to Heroku.

What heroku does not generally support is hosting user uploads eg if you let users submit files to the server via a form.

I used Dropbox a bit as a general CDN when I was learning but the speed is aweful and the URLs are crazy.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you did it? And which speed are you talking about?

Comment: I never used it with Rails but more to host static HTML and images - and at that it is a pretty crappy solution - occasionally Dropbox would take forever to deliver a file. Just commit your files to Heroku instead - heroku allows a pretty large slug size and the performance is decent.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://cloudinary.com/ for free CDN instead of S3 or dropbox.

Comment: is it support pdf upload ??

Comment: Yes it does, you can check it's documentation for more info.

Comment: it is not free. dropbox has 1tb for free; it'd cost thousands monthly on cloudinary, if not more